# Geo coordinates of upazilas in Bangladesh

Tags: geospatial, geocoding, county

In order to add markers in map, I need geo coordinates of [upazilas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upazilas_of_Bangladesh) (upazila offices) in Bangladesh. Something like this GitHub repo [bangladesh-geo](https://github.com/nuhil/bangladesh-geocode) should do my job, but unfortunately the SQL tables have longitude and latitude of districts only, not of upazilas (i.e., sub-districts).

Does the Internet have such a database? Or can anyone help me write a script pull coordinates in CSV, JSON, etc. format?

Comment: [From Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20%3FuLabel%20%3Fc%20where%20%7B%3Fu%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ620471.%20optional%20%7B%3Fu%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fc%7D%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%7D)

Comment: Wonderful! Why don't you write it as answer?

Comment: This is great and very helpful but I need geocoordinates at district level

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikidata contains upazilas' coordinates from Wikipedias and GeoNames:

```
SELECT ?divisionLabel ?districtLabel ?upazilaLabel ?upazila ?lat ?long ?fromLabel {
  ?upazila wdt:P31 wd:Q620471.
  ?upazila wdt:P131 ?district . ?district wdt:P31 wd:Q152732.
  ?district wdt:P131 ?division . ?division wdt:P31 wd:Q878040.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?upazila p:P625 ?statement. 
    ?statement psv:P625 [wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat; wikibase:geoLongitude ?long]
    OPTIONAL {
      ?statement prov:wasDerivedFrom [pr:P143|pr:P248 ?from] 
    }
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} ORDER BY ?divisionLabel ?districtLabel ?upazilaLabel
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FdivisionLabel%20%3FdistrictLabel%20%3FupazilaLabel%20%3Fupazila%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%20%3FfromLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fupazila%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ620471.%0A%20%20%3Fupazila%20wdt%3AP131%20%3Fdistrict%20.%20%3Fdistrict%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ152732.%0A%20%20%3Fdistrict%20wdt%3AP131%20%3Fdivision%20.%20%3Fdivision%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ878040.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fupazila%20p%3AP625%20%3Fstatement.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20psv%3AP625%20%5Bwikibase%3AgeoLatitude%20%3Flat%3B%20wikibase%3AgeoLongitude%20%3Flong%5D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20prov%3AwasDerivedFrom%20%5Bpr%3AP143%7Cpr%3AP248%20%3Ffrom%5D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3FdivisionLabel%20%3FdistrictLabel%20%3FupazilaLabel)

---

For some upazilas, Wikidata contains coordinates from several sources. The query returns pair of coordinates from all sources. Ask on SO, if you need only one pair of coordinates in that case.

P.S. I don't know, whether these points are upazila offices, or upazila centroids, or something else...